# Why "500 internal server error" with index.php permission 666?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, web-hosting

In a fresh Wordpress site (this may be valid to other sites too), Having **index.php** permissions set to **0666** makes

> Error 500: Internal server error

But simply changing its permissions to **0644** solves the problem. **Why?**

Comment: 500 error due to exception.. Might be your script falling.

Comment: 500 is a general response when PHP throws exception, but error reporting is disabled. Enable error reporting to see what is actually failing.

Comment: It happens with a fresh Wordpress installation. So it's not a problem in my website.

Comment: @Auris Please tell my how to enable this kind of error reporting.

Comment: @Meena have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache configuration may have some php handler like suphp:

http://www.suphp.org/Home.html

> suPHP is a tool for executing PHP scripts with the permissions of their owners. It consists of an Apache module (mod_suphp) and a setuid root binary (suphp) that is called by the Apache module to change the uid of the process executing the PHP interpreter.

Since suPHP makes your PHP scripts run with the same permissions as your regular user account, you do not need group or world write access or execute access for files and PHP will even prevent files from running that are group or world writable or executable as a security precaution.